# Is there a way to show Product Attributes if it only has one value?

Tags: commerce

I have products in my shop with the attribute "language". If more than one language attribute was set, the language field is displayed in the product view as it should. But if the product has only one language attribute, the field is hidden. Is there a way to always display the field, even if only one value was set?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you're using Drupal 7 or Drupal 8. In Drupal 7, our **Add to Cart form** display formatter has an option to "Show attribute widgets even if the Add to Cart form only represents one product." You can find this by clicking the configuration gear for the formatter in your **Manage Display** settings for the node type you use for product displays.